# MySQL upgrade from left join to something similar as FULL join

Tags: mysql

Sorry for asking here this but I need help and google is not being nice.

I have the following table Products

```
SELECT 
      COUNT(CASE when core.kits.Location = core.suppliers.id THEN 1 END) as total,  
      COUNT(CASE when core.kits.cp = 1 THEN 1 END) as used, 
      core.suppliers.id, core.suppliers.name, core.suppliers.email,      
      core.suppliers.cperson, core.suppliers.adress, core.suppliers.phone
FROM core.kits
    LEFT join core.suppliers on core.kits.Location = core.suppliers.id
WHERE core.suppliers.id is not null
AND  banned=0
GROUP BY core.suppliers.id
ORDER BY name ASC
LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0
```

but does not give me all the suppliers with zeros for the ones who have no appearance in kits.

Then in I do

```
SELECT 
      COUNT(CASE when core.kits.Location = core.suppliers.id THEN 1 END) as total,  
      COUNT(CASE when core.kits.cp = 1 THEN 1 END) as used, 
      core.suppliers.id, core.suppliers.name, core.suppliers.email,      
      core.suppliers.cperson, core.suppliers.adress, core.suppliers.phone
FROM core.suppliers
    LEFT join core.suppliers on core.suppliers.id = core.kits.Location
WHERE core.suppliers.id is not null
AND  banned=0
GROUP BY core.suppliers.id
ORDER BY name ASC
LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0
```

I get all suppliers and correct numbers but the query takes 8 seconds instead of 1s. Any ideas how can I get all the suppliers with the count of stocks in 1s?

cheers.

Comment: Its always a good idea to show us the schema for all the tables involved

Comment: The query is malformed. `WHERE core.suppliers.id is not null` silently converts the `LEFT JOIN` into an inner join.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the suppliers, even those that do not appear in `kits` you should do a `LEFT` join of `suppliers` to `kits`:

```
SELECT COUNT(k.Location) AS total,  
       COUNT(CASE WHEN k.cp = 1 THEN 1 END) AS used, 
       s.id, s.name, s.email, s.cperson, s.adress, s.phone
FROM core.suppliers s LEFT JOIN core.kits k 
ON k.Location = s.id
WHERE banned=0
GROUP BY s.id
ORDER BY s.name ASC
LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0;
```

I assume that `core.suppliers.id` is the primary key of `suppliers`, so that the conition:

```
core.suppliers.id is not null
```

is not needed.

Also, if the column `banned` is contained in the table `kits`, then the condition should be moved in the `ON` clause:

```
ON k.Location = s.id AND k.banned=0
```

and the `WHERE` clause should be removed.